# Failed to find provider null for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am facing two inter related issue,
I am facing following issue in Android Oreo device,

```
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_REMOTE_RSSI_UPDATED flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.linka.linkaapikit.module.widget.LockGattUpdateReceiver$1@762cfd9
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args_52197(LoadedApk.java:1315)
    at android.app.-$Lambda$aS31cHIhRx41653CMnd4gZqshIQ.$m$7(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.app.-$Lambda$aS31cHIhRx41653CMnd4gZqshIQ.run(Unknown Source:39)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider null for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2005)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1951)
    at android.content.IContentService$Stub$Proxy.notifyChange(IContentService.java:801)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:2049)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:2000)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:1970)
    at com.activeandroid.Model.save(Model.java:162)
```

After that i find following solutions,

**add in Android Manifest**

```
 <provider
        android:name="com.activeandroid.content.ContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.myapp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        />
```

But after adding this line i got another issue that are following,

```
 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Superclass org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams of org.apache.http.params.SyncBasicHttpParams is declared final (declaration of 'org.apache.http.params.SyncBasicHttpParams' appears in /data/app/com.kolonishare-6KsxqUHOK_Q45cGI0D0bHg==/base.apk:classes16.dex)
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
    at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.scanForModelClasses(ModelInfo.java:187)
    at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.scanForModel(ModelInfo.java:152)
    at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.<init>(ModelInfo.java:63)
    at com.activeandroid.Cache.initialize(Cache.java:66)
    at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:44)
    at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:34)
    at com.activeandroid.content.ContentProvider.onCreate(ContentProvider.java:39)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1919)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1894)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6285)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5851)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5772)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I clean and also rebuild project, invalidate restart but getting same error.

Answer (score -1):

you need put your xml in this

```
<provider android:name="com.activeandroid.content.ContentProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" />
```